# R: storing data with same ID into lists

Tags: r, list

Since I'll try to reproduce an own code for Cross-Validation (for exercise purposes), I want to split first my data into 10 different subsamples. My idea is to generate random ID's and store them the data into the 10 chunks. However I'm still a beginner and have no idea, how can I store the data with the same ID into one element of the list.

```
#Generating short example
x <- rnorm(100)
#Number of Folds
nfolds <- 10
#Date length
N <- length(x)
#Generating random ID's
foldid <- sample(rep(seq(nfolds), length = N))
#Storing folds
store_folds <- vector(mode="list",length=10)
```

Comment: r u looking for `split(x, foldid)`?

Comment: wow, thanks ! Thats works